# Continuous Version of Law of total probability for random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, stochastic-calculus

Let $X$ be random variable which admits
a density function $f_X$. Then due to [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Continuous_case)
there exist continuous version of the
[law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)

which states that for every event $A$ on
$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ there holds the equality

$$  P(A)= \int_{- \infty}^{+\infty} P(A \ \vert \ X=x)f_X(x) dx  $$

How it can be proved?
Moreover can this statement be adapted to a version
about denisity functions?

Say $X$ and $Y$ are two real RV with density functions
$f_X$ and $f_Y$. Let $f_{(X,Y)}$ be the common density function
of $(X,Y)$. Then does hold

$$ f_X(x)= \int_{- \infty}^{+\infty} f_{(X,Y)}(x,y) dy   $$

and if yes, how to prove it?

Comment: The correct version of your first equation is $$P(A)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(A\mid X=x)f_X(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: right, thank you!

Comment: One way to prove the first is iterated expectations $$P[A] = E[1_A] = E[E[1_A|X]]$$ where $1_A$ is an indicator function that is 1 if $A$ occurs and $0$ else. One way to prove the second is to show $g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy$ has the property of a PDF for $X$, being nonnegative and satisfying $\int_{-\infty}^x g(t)dt = P[X\leq x]$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Michael: How do you obtain the equality $E[1_A] = E[E[1_A|X]]$?

Comment: In general the "law of iterated expectations" says that for any random variables $Y$ and $X$ such that $E[|Y|]<\infty$ we have $$E[Y] = E[E[Y|X]]$$  So define $Y=1_A$.